# python manage.py runserver causes AppRegistryNotReady exception with views that extend ProtectedResourceView

Tags: python, django

Environment:

- Ubuntu GNOME 14.04
- Python 2.7.6 (using a virtualenv)
- Django 1.7.1 (inside the virtualenv)
- Custom user model
- django-oauth-toolkit 0.7.2 (installed via pip) (https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit)
- Eclipse Kepler SR2 (build id 20140224-0627)
- PyDev 3.8.0.201409251235

I am using Django and django-oauth-toolkit to create a RESTful backend API for an iOS and Android app.  I have done this successfully before for a different mobile app using Python 2.6.6 and Django 1.4.8 on CentOS 6.5, but am having trouble in the current environment.

I have a class that extends django-oauth-toolkit's `ProtectedResourceView` (http://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.org/en/0.7.2/views/details.html#generic):

```
from oauth2_provider.views.generic import ProtectedResourceView
from django.http.response import HttpResponse

class TestEndpoint(ProtectedResourceView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse("Hello World!")
```

The file for this view is located in `/home/user/workspace/MyProject/MyApp/views/test_endpoint.py`.  It is imported into the views package in `/home/user/workspace/MyProject/MyApp/views/__init__.py`.

The endpoint is mapped in my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from MyApp.views import UnprotectedEndpoint
from MyApp.views.test_endpoint import TestEndpoint

urlpatterns = patterns('api_v1',
    url(r'^account/create/', UnprotectedEndpoint.as_view()),
    url(r'^test/', TestEndpoint.as_view()),
)
```

After entering the virtualenv, I run `python manage.py runserver` and get the following error:

```
(MyVirtualEnv)user@ubuntu-laptop:~/workspace/MyProject$ python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/user/virtualenvs/MyVirtualEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/user/virtualenvs/MyVirtualEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/user/virtualenvs/MyVirtualEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/user/virtualenvs/MyVirtualEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/user/virtualenvs/MyVirtualEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 87, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/user/workspace/MyProject/MyApp/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import urls
  File "/home/user/workspace/MyProject/MyApp/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from MyApp.views import UnprotectedEndpoint
  File "/home/user/workspace/MyProject/MyApp/views/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from test_endpoint import TestEndpoint
  File "/home/user/workspace/MyProject/MyApp/views/test_endpoint.py", line 1, in <module>
    from oauth2_provider.views.generic import ProtectedResourceView
  File "/home/user/virtualenvs/MyVirtualEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2_provider/views/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .base import AuthorizationView, TokenView
  File "/home/user/virtualenvs/MyVirtualEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2_provider/views/base.py", line 13, in <module>
    from ..forms import AllowForm
  File "/home/user/virtualenvs/MyVirtualEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2_provider/forms.py", line 22, in <module>
    class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
  File "/home/user/virtualenvs/MyVirtualEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2_provider/forms.py", line 26, in RegistrationForm
    class Meta:
  File "/home/user/virtualenvs/MyVirtualEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2_provider/forms.py", line 27, in Meta
    model = get_application_model()
  File "/home/user/virtualenvs/MyVirtualEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2_provider/models.py", line 241, in get_application_model
    app_model = get_model(app_label, model_name)
  File "/home/user/virtualenvs/MyVirtualEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 199, in get_model
    self.check_models_ready()
  File "/home/user/virtualenvs/MyVirtualEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 131, in check_models_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

When I remove the `TestEndpoint` from `__init__.py` and `urls.py`, the server starts up fine.  But when I import a view that extends `ProtectedResourceView`, the `AppRegistryNotReady` exception is thrown. Why doesn't Django like that view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in `django-oauth-toolkit` in conjunction with Django 1.7, see here: https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit/issues/151

You can use the workaround that was posted to the issue, or just switch back to Django 1.6 and wait for a fix for `django-oauth-toolkit`.

==========

**UPDATE from OP**:

This issue has been fixed in django-oauth-toolkit 0.8 and released to PyPI as of 27 March 2015. I have tested and confirmed this with the project described in the original question.

Comment: Where would the workaround code be placed? In the source for `django-oauth-toolkit`?

Comment: yep. I'd suggest to fork the repo and clone it to add the changes.